# Cached immutable value: avoid lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching

Suppose I have the following code:

```
struct Obj {
    mutable bool valueIsCached_;
    mutable int value_;
    const int parameter_;

    Obj (int parameter) : valueIsCached_ (false), parameter_ (parameter) {
    }

    int getValue () const {
        if (!valueIsCached) {
            value_ = calculateValue ();  // #1
            valueIsCached_ = true;       // #2
        }
        return value_;
    }

 private:
    int calculateValue () {
        /* calculate value based on parameter and return it;
           return value only depends on value of parameter_
           (no side effects; no dependence on global state)
        */
    }
 };
```

This code is, obviously, thread-safe if the compiler does not reorder the lines marked #1 and #2. The worst thing which can happen is multiple calculation of `value_`. The code, however, gets thread-unsafe as soon as we cannot guarantee that #2 happens after #1.

1. How can we avoid this?
2. Do things get worse if the type of `value_` is, e.g., a `struct`?

Comment: It isn't thread safe as written, regardless in the reordering.

Comment: exactly. Try to visualize a worst case scenario with two threads A and B 'simultaneously' calling `getValue()`: suppose A just executed `if (!valueIsCached)` and the system decides to switch to thread B which has way higher priority and executes until `return value_`. Now A can run again, but the damage is done already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy initialized caching... how do I make it thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097439/lazy-initialized-caching-how-do-i-make-it-thread-safe)

Comment: @RyanGuthrie Why isn't this thread safe if we prevent reordering? In stijn's example, A goes into the if statement. Then B comes in and calculates and sets `_value`. Now A executes again and calculates and sets `_value` again, but since `_value` only depends on `_parameter`, the value of `_value` stays the same, and both threads continue with the correct result.

Comment: @stijn No, it is *not* a duplicate in my opinion, as I am willing to accept possible multiple calculation of `_value` in exchange for avoiding the cost of locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert a barrier. Here's code for VC++:

```
int getValue () const {
    if (!valueIsCached_) {
        value_ = calculateValue ();  // #1
        _WriteBarrier();             // force value_ to be written first.
        valueIsCached_ = true;       // #2
    }
    return value_;
}
```

Note that this is assuming `calculateValue` is thread-safe, because it can be called by multiple threads, and that writing to `value_` and `valueIsCached_` more than once is safe.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to be what I have been looking for.